# Stuck while updating the embedded document in mongoose, nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have simple json file with structrea as shown below.

```
{
    "SchoolId" : "123456",
    "SchoolName" : "abc",
    "Class" : [
        {
            "ID" : "ABC",
            "Name" : "puc",
            "Student" : [
                {
                    "Name" : "RAM"
                    "ClassName" : "secondary"
                },
                {
                    "Name" : "SAM"
                    "ClassName" : "Higher secondary"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

//Start

```
exports.putbyid = function(req, res) {
    console.log("putbyid in roletcontroller");
    role.findById(req.params.SchoolId, function (err, schooldetails) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }.......................
```

//End

I want to update the data inside both the embedded documents 'Class' and 'Student', so how exactly should I write code for updating the embedded documents 'Class' and 'Student', I tried a couple of techniques but that didn't work, so plz tell me is there any ready made solution for this requirement. else plz let me know if there is any other website which tells how to write code for this type of requirements.

Comment: Which "embedded document" are you referring to? Can you name the json appropriately? Its unclear what needs to be updated with.

Comment: I want to update the 'entitlements' and 'privileges' sections.

Comment: Your questions is not clear. do you want to update the `privilege` array inside the `entitlements` array?. If so, You have to add `obj.markModified('field name')` for mixed type object in mongodb. if you want more info on this i will help you